# CodeIgniter: Validation Not Stopping

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I am pretty sure that I have just missed something very obvious but to my eyes I cannot work out what.  The empty form validation is working correctly but its when I enter any random values into the input boxes and click login it shows `'This is working fine';` so I have a feeling that it is something to do with my callback function.

I am trying to make is so the person can login with their username or password

**Validation:**

```
'loginUser' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'userLoginUsername',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'userLoginPassword',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|callback__check_login|xss_clean|sha1'
        )

    )// End of login user array
```

**Callback:**

```
function _check_login($username, $password)
{
    if($this->users_model->login_check($username,$password))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_login', 'Sorry you have entered an incorrect %s ');
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function login()
    {
        if($this->form_validation->run('loginUser') == FALSE)
        {
            $data['success'] = '';
        }else{
            echo 'This is working fine';
        }

        $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
        $data['pageTitle'] = "User Login";
        $this->load->view('frontend/assets/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/user_login', $data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/assets/footer');

    }   
}
```

**Model:**

```
function login_check($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('userName,userEmail,userPassword');
        $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->where('userName', $username, 'userEmail', $username, 'userPassword' , $password, 'userActive', 1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<h1><?php echo $companyName; echo nbs(1);?> - <?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>

    <div class="formComments">
        <p class="error"><?php echo validation_errors();?></p>
        <p class="success"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></p>
        </div>

<div class="user_login">
    <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="login" >
        <input type="text" name="userLoginUsername" id="userLoginUsername" class="input-small" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="userLoginPassword" id="userLoginPassword" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" class"btn">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code

if data is verified by model ie `TRUE` returned callback `_check_login` will `return FALSE` to `login()` because of

```
if($this->users_model->login_check($username,$password))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_login', 'Sorry you have entered an incorrect %s ');
        return FALSE;
    }
```

hence condition

```
if($this->form_validation->run('loginUser') == FALSE)
```

will be succeeded and it will set  `$data['success'] = '';`

for wrong input or empty validation model `returns FALSE` so

```
if($this->users_model->login_check($username,$password))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_login', 'Sorry you have entered an incorrect %s ');
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE; /* login check failed control comes here*/
    }
```

hence

```
if($this->form_validation->run('loginUser') == FALSE)
    {
        $data['success'] = '';
    }else{
        echo 'This is working fine'; /*control comes here now*/
    }
```

change

```
if($this->users_model->login_check($username,$password))
```

to

```
if(!$this->users_model->login_check($username,$password))
```

and it should work

hope this helps

*EDIT****_*_**

well, just figured out something you are missing might be creating the issue. the callback you are setting in the rule array

```
array(
            'field' => 'userLoginPassword',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|callback__check_login['.$_POST['userLoginUsername'].']|xss_clean|sha1'
        )
```

must be

```
array(
            'field' => 'userLoginPassword',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|callback__check_login['.$_POST['userLoginUsername'].']|xss_clean|sha1'
        )
```

because the callback function is expecting 2 values and the way you are using it only send password field to it. also with this rearrange the callback argument to

```
function _check_login($password, $username)
```

so the first value be password and second be username. for checking 'userActive' remove it from the where clause and check its value if query returned some record

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1){
    /* check its value if 1 do something as you asked in comment*/
```

Comment: Hey,  I have tried that but it seems its not passing any login values and just giving the check_login.  I have also updated my question model as I would like the account to login if it is active.  How would I make that account error if it was not active.  would that be a use of an if else(value)?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that's a lot of code but I spotted this:

In your controller you use a validation rule to check for the right user data; besides that I wouldn't do like that, since properly speaking it isn't a "form validation" rule, what I see is that if your user exists and his credentials are correct you return TRUE.

That's fine, but in your validation rule you have:

```
if($this->users_model->login_check($username,$password))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_login', 'Sorry you have entered an incorrect %s ');
        return FALSE;
```

which measn that when the model returns TRUE (user is ok), your validation returns FALSE! and that means when the user is right your validation doesn't succeed, and when your user is "wrong" (see your "random input") the rule returns TRUE, making it a success.

I don't have time to look further now, but skimming the code everything looks ok apart from this. SO, just change that line to

```
if(!$this->users_model->login_check($username,$password))
    {
```

i.e. "if the model returns FALSE, make the rule return FALSE too". Hope it is clear.

Comment: Hey,  I have tried that but it seems its not passing any login values and just giving the check_login.  I have also updated my question model as I would like the account to login if it is active.  How would I make that account error if it was not active.  would that be a use of an if else(value)?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this line here:

```
if($this->form_validation->run('loginUser') == FALSE)
```

You should either remove 'loginUser' or pop in a variable, like $loginUser, something feels funny about your array.

Comment: Hey,  That is correct see here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig